# Creating 2D array to play audio in left and right channel in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, sound

I'm new to matlab sound processing and I am trying to create a 2D array for the sound code below. I have to make the sound have 400 samples(i.e 10ms) at 20hz, but having trouble getting the code to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
The steps are:
(1)    Construct a two-dimensional array (n x 2  array, i.e., 2 columns, n rows, n is the number of samples per sound channel).  The array is the sound signal, the first column is the sound for the left channel (left speaker), the second column is the sound for the right channel (right speaker)
(2)    Then play the sound.

```
Fs = 44100;
t = [0:4/Fs:4-4/Fs];
freq = 20;
f1 = sin(2*pi*freq*t);
f2 = sin(2*pi*2*freq*t);
%Sound 1
sound(f1,Fs);
%Sound 2
sound(f2,Fs);
%Play Consecutive
f12 = [f1 f2];
sound(f12,Fs);
%Play together
f_12 = [f1+f2];
sound(f_12,Fs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 20 Hz was a little hard to hear with my speakers, I've changed the main frequency to 600 Hz. I guess it should work:

```
clc;
clear all;

Fs = 44100; 
N = 40000; % sample size
t = (1:N)*(1/Fs); 
freq = 600; 

sound_array = zeros(N, 2); % initializes a N x 2 matrix
sound_array(:,1) = sin(2*pi*freq*t); 
sound_array(:,2) = sin(2*pi*2*freq*t); 

% Sound 1 
sound(sound_array(:,1),Fs); 

% Sound 2 
sound(sound_array(:,2),Fs); 

% Play the first column at left channel and the second column at the right
% channel
sound(sound_array,Fs);
```

In fact, if you use the entire array as input in `sound`, the first column will go to the left channel and the second column to the right channel.

Comment: Playing the sound wasn't the issue...how would I create the 2D array for the left and right channel?

Comment: @Asau7610, sorry! I've just edited the answer.

Comment: I keep getting an error saying " attempt to execute script sound as a function...error in Soundcreate (line 14) sound(array(:,1,Fs);

Comment: Also @lucasn what does the N = 4000 stand for. And the 20hz is being played so that just outsid human hearing but a recorder object can still record and read the sound.

Comment: `N` is the sample size. The vector `t` contains `N` time samples acquired at 44100 Hz. Then we use it to obtain the sinusoids samples.

Comment: Ohh ok I understand now @lucasn but did you see the error I get when I play the code you changed and I tried to comment out and we if that might fix it but all the sound() throw an error.

Comment: And Lucas how can I take away the bottom half of the code and just have one sound play out the left and other out the right. I don't need the consecutive part etc and sorry for the questions I only use matlab for image processing and this is for a sound project

Comment: This error did not happen to me. I guess that you have in your path a function called `array`, so the script is trying to call this function instead of referencing an array. Try changing the name of the variable `array` in this code.

Comment: Check out the code, I've re-edited it! :)

Comment: It's still throwing the same error @lucasn

Comment: Did you repost the code @lucasn and thank you so much for your help

Comment: yes, check it once more.

Comment: if i wanted to I have a play function that is called twice, each plays a channel (a column of the two dimensional array) in both speakers. Meaning the sound plays alternatively. What I am trying to do is to play both channel at the same time but silence a channel and have the elements set in the corresponding column to 0. Like 1 channel is live on the left playing 111 and the other channel is silent at 000 but they switch back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start at the construction of the vector *t*. The assignment says to generate a signal with a length of 400 samples. However, due to the way you constructed *t*, your signals have a length of 44100 samples. In the way I'd recommend to generate signals we need a vector that contains the indices of the samples our signal will eventually have, so

```
t = (0:399)';
```

This gives us a column vector (because I used the transpose operator `'`) of size 400x1, containing the indices of the samples of our signal-to-be.

Now your assignment says to generate a signal with a frequency of 20 Hz and let it run for 400 samples. I think that is a little bit odd, since a signal of that frequency does not complete a full cycle in only 400 samples with a sampling rate of 44100 Hertz. Anyway, we will continue as asked of us by your assignment.

We now have to convert the frequency of 20 Hertz to the angular frequency that depends on *Fs*. To do that, we use the following piece of code:

```
w = 2*pi*(f/Fs);
```

with `f = 20;`. Together with *t*, *w* will now be our input for the `sin()` function to generate the signal. This is now trivial:

```
f1 = sin(w*t);
```

The next part of the exercise seems to be to combine two mono signals of the kind we just created into a stereo signal.

> (1) Construct a two-dimensional array (n x 2 array, i.e., 2 columns, n rows, n is the number of samples per sound channel).

Do achieve that, you should look into how vectors (or matrices) are concatenated in MATLAB. Since *f1* and *f2* are column vectors, to combine them into a matrix of size 400x2, we can use

```
F12 = [f1 f2];
```

If we wanted to concatenate them, like you have also done in your code, we would have to use

```
F12 = [f1; f2];
```

In order to play back these signals, I'd recommend using `soundsc()`, which normalizes the audio before playback (so it doesn't damage your speakers in case of high amplitudes):

```
soundsc(F12, Fs);
```

Comment: Nice resonse. Playing back a sine of amplitude 10.0f won’t damage loudspeakers in normal circumstances. The waveform will be clipped by the d/a converter to a square wave and sound loud and distorted and unpleasant. The electronics of laptop loudspeakers are usually designed to be robust.